# Cloning iterators in Java

Tags: java, list, iterator

I have a LinkedList in Java, an iterator to browse the list and I would like to clone the iterator to do some temporary "look ahead" processing of the list with respect to the position of the original iterator.

I understand that cloning an iterator is not possible in every situation, but is there a way to clone an iterator to a LinkedList (or save and restore its state)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It would be possible but Sun made sure you can't (by making the class private).

But maybe you can achieve what you want using a `listIterator()` instead of a plain `iterator()`. A `ListIterator` can move in both directions.

Comment: That's ok. I'll save the number of steps ahead then go back that number of steps to restore the state.

Answer (score 1):

With the `ListIterator` you can store the index of the next element, and can get a new `ListIterator` based on that index.

Something like this (Java 1.5 example):

```
LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();  
ListIterator<Integer> lit = list.listIterator(0);  
<<do something here  >>  
int index = lit.nextIndex();  
ListIterator<Integer> litclone = list.listIterator(index);
```

Comment: But getting an iterator from the index would mean to browse the list again from the beginning. It seems to me a very expensive way to produce a clone of what is, essentially, a pointer in other languages like C++ with the standard library.