# Clone an Iterator in Java?

Tags: java, iterator

In a game I have a list of players, let's say like this:

```
LinkedList<String> players = new LinkedList<String>();
```

I want to let each player interact with each of the other players, so I write two nested loops:

```
Iterator<String> i1 = players.iterator();
while (i1.hasNext()) {
    String p1 = i1.next();
    Iterator<String> i2 = players.iterator();
    // But I want to do this: Iterator<String> i2 = i1.clone();
    while (i2.hasNext()) {
        String p2 = i2.next();
        System.out.println("Interact: " + p1 + ", " + p2);
    }
}
```

Since I only want each pair of players to interact once, I want to start the inner loop with the player after the outer loop's current player. So I want to clone the iterator, but that doesn't compile.

So, what should I do instead?

Comment: Why not just use an `ArrayList<String>` instead?  An algorithm using positions would be trivial with that data structure.

Comment: Wouldn't this result in pairing player A with A?

Comment: @Kirk: Yes, an ArrayList would work, but since I may have to insert and remove players in the middle of the list, I want a LinkedList.

Comment: @matt b: Yes. Thankyou. Fixed (I hope). (This is what happens when I can't test my code. It is _always_ wrong!)

Comment: @Thomas, it's just that it's usually the case that reshuffling an array is faster than using a `LinkedList` since the cost of instantiating the list element entries is usually higher than simply moving memory around.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for the replies and comments. (And in the end, I used ArrayList.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cloning iterators in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542566/cloning-iterators-in-java)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The following will do it:

```
ListIterator<String> i1 = players.listIterator(0);
while (i1.hasNext()) {
    String p1 = i1.next();
    ListIterator<String> i2 = players.listIterator(i1.nextIndex());
    while (i2.hasNext()) {
        String p2 = i2.next();
        System.out.println("Interact: " + p1 + ", " + p2);
    }
}
```

It relies on the [`ListIterator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html)'s ability to start from the given position and to also know its current position.

Comment: aix strikes again. +1, beautiful solution.

Comment: Thanks! But, one question: How does the listIterator(int) method work - it doesn't start at the head of the list and iterate its way to the given position, does it?

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy: That's not specified as part of the interface. However, given the nature of the linked list, at almost certainly does. On the other hand, I am not aware of any solution that would avoid this.

Comment: @aix, +1 on your comment. There is one obvious solution however, if the OP is willing to go from *O(1)* to *O(n)* memory consumption, see my answer.

Comment: I ended up changing my LinkedList to an ArrayList. It may be a bit slower in other places, but at least I won't have the (mostly aesthetic) problem of unnecessary traversal. But I still don't understand why they decided not to let you clone the iterator. I even thought about using a purpose-built list, with clonable iterators, but I'll wait with that until I know I need the performance.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy For Java's LinkedList, it either starts from the start or from the end, whichever is shorter.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to [aix answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758202/clone-an-iterator-in-java/7758296#7758296), I'd like to point out that however you create an iterator starting at a specific index, it's bound to be a linear operation. If it wasn't, you would be able to do arbitrary access to the list in constant time using

```
elementN = createIterator(linkedList, N).next();
```

which would be contradictory.

In your situation I therefore believe that the most efficient solution would actually be to do

```
List<String> tmp = new ArrayList<String>(players);
for (int p1 = 0; p1 < tmp.size(); p1++)
    for (int p2 = p1+1; p2 < tmp.size(); p2++)
        System.out.println("Interact: " + tmp.get(p1) + ", " + tmp.get(p2));
```

Note however, that it is *still* the same complexity as the solution by aix; *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* but probably with a smaller constant factor.

Comment: I disagree. If you have an iterator pointing to the index you want, you should be able to get to that index instantly, so long as the interface permits. This imaginary `i1.clone()` method would be `O(1)` whereas `players.listIterator(i1.nextIndex())` is `O(n)`. The `clone()` method would supply the cloned iterator with the node it currently holds, eliminating the need to iterate up to that point in the list.

Comment: In principle you are right. The imaginary clone method would be trivial to implement. In this case however, OP was most likely referring to java.util.LinkedList which does not support cloning. Many questions on this topic. See for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963399/how-can-i-make-a-copy-of-an-iterator-in-java

Answer (score 1):

For a solution that avoids the linear cost associated to `listIterator(int)` (NPE's answer),  see my [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35235485).
In brief, as long as you don't care about the order the list is visited, you can start the outer loop from the last element and iterate back, and start the inner loop from the first element and iterate forward until the two iterators meet. The call to list.listIterator(list.size()) is fast because list is a LinkedList, i.e. a doubly-linked list, and accessing the last element does not require iterating through the list. See example below:

```
public static int iterRevIterator(List<Integer> list) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(ListIterator<Integer> outer = list.listIterator(list.size()); outer.hasPrevious(); ) {
        Integer oVal = outer.previous();
        for(ListIterator<Integer> inner = list.listIterator(); inner.nextIndex() <= outer.previousIndex(); ) {
            sum += oVal * inner.next();
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```