# Elegant way to do "downward" iterations with iterators

Tags: java, iterator

For example, for a list {1,2,3,4}, I must compare the pairs (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,3), (2,4), (3,4). The way with normal for loops is:

```
for(i=0 ; i<list.size() ; i++){
    for(j=i+1 ; j<list.size() ; j++){
    //do stuff with list[i] and list[j];
    }
}
```

Can I do something like this with iterators (see below)?

```
for (int i : list){
    for(int j : [list after index i]){
    //do stuff with list[i] and list[j];
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clone an Iterator in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758202/clone-an-iterator-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not *that* elegant, but possible:

```
int lastIndex = list.size()-1;
for (Object i : list) {
  for (Object j : list.sublist(list.indexOf(i), list.size()-1)) {
    // do what has to be done
  }
}
```

Comment: And performance is bad, `list.indexOf(i)` is an O(n) operation. Using a traditional for loop is better.

Answer (score 1):

Since the index of the items is clearly important here, I think you should stick with the old index-based for loop in this case. It might not be quite as pretty, but it will be explicit.

If you're doing this a lot you could encapsulate the code in a method and pass it a method to invoke per-pair.

Answer (score 1):

This still uses nested loops, but uses a [ListIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) instead.
A ListIterator can be obtained through the [listIterator(idx) method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#listIterator%28int%29) of the `List` interface. Its not really more elegant than the for loop but might perform better if the list is not randomly accessible, for example a `LinkedList`.

```
for (ListIterator i=list.listIterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
    Object a = i.next();
    for (Iterator j=list.listIterator(i.previousIndex()); j.hasNext(); ) {
        Object b = j.next();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own [Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) to do this. You'll also have to create a simple wrapper objects to let you return two items at once (it is very annoying that there is no tuple type built in to Java!).

Simply by implementing the `Iterator` however will not let you use it directly in a `for` loop. You'll have to do something like this instead:

```
Iterator<MyPairObject> iterator = new MyIterator(list);
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    ...
}
```

However, if you subclass the `list` class you're using you can override the `iterator()` method and return your own iterator - then you'll be able to use your custom list class and it's iterator directly in a for loop.