# Iterate two distinct elements in set?

Tags: java

I want to get the pair of every two distinct element in set. I think that if using for-each loop I have to iterate with complexity of O(n^2). If using iterator, I can have two iterators where the second one points to the next of the first one, which means for the second loop I don't have to loop from the start. However, I can't seem to print my method correctly.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>();
    s.add("A");
    s.add("B");
    s.add("C");
    s.add("D");
    Iterator<String> itr1 = s.iterator();
    while (itr1.hasNext()){
        Iterator<String> itr2 = itr1;
        String s1 = itr1.next();
        while (itr2.hasNext()){
            String s2 = itr2.next();
            System.out.println(s1 + " " + s2);
        }
    }
}
```

The output is

```
A B
A C
A D
```

However what I want is:

```
A B
A C
A D
B C
B D
C D
```

Comment: note that set does not maintain order .

Comment: I would guess your issue comes from the line `Iterator<String> itr2 = itr1;`. Because you set them equal to eachother, by calling `itr2.next()`, you're modifying the state of the first iterator. I think you might want to clone the first iterator at that point. Here's a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758202/clone-an-iterator-in-java) to look at.

Comment: Jordan, note that for Big O notation, it doesn't matter if you don't repeat the entirely inner loop again (i.e start from i+1, or next of iterator). It will still been considered n^2 complexity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that

```
Iterator<String> itr2 = itr1;
```

does what you think it does. It means that `itr2` is literally the same object as `itr1`. It is not a deep or stateful copy.

This would be easier if you were working with a list, since we could rely on indices for order. In order to use `Iterator` and `Set`, you'll need to maintain a collection of objects that you've already used:

```
Iterator<String> itr1 = s.iterator();
Set<String> used = new HashSet<>(); // track the elements that have been used in the first column
while (itr1.hasNext()) {
    Iterator<String> itr2 = s.iterator(); // a new iterator
    String s1 = itr1.next();
    used.add(s1); // track what we've used
    while (itr2.hasNext()) {
        String s2 = itr2.next();
        if (used.contains(s2));
            continue; // we've alread used s2
        System.out.println(s1 + " " + s2);
    }
}
```

Theoretically, it would be better to use an array (or list) and `for` loop to do what you want to do:

```
String[] elements = s.toArray(new String[s.size()]);
for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
    String s1 = elements[i];
    // loop through all successive elements
    for (int j = i + 1; j < elements.length; ++j) {
        String s2 = elements[j];
        System.out.println(s1 + " " + s2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're general logic is right, your problem is that the line

```
Iterator<String> itr2 = itr1;
```

does not copy the iterator and instead you are using the same iterator object for both loops.

I think this honestly might be a case where using a simple for loop with an index variable is a lot easier than using loops iterators.

However since you cannot iterate over a set using an index variable i would recommend either using a simple List, or at least converting the Set to a List for this specific function:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
    s.add("A");
    s.add("B");
    s.add("C");
    s.add("D");

    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
        String s1 = s.get(i);
        for (int x = i+1; x < s.size(); x++) {
            String s2 = s.get(x);
            System.out.println(s1 + " " + s2);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Iterator itr2 = itr1;  will result in both variables pointing to the same interator.

1.) don't use an unordered set
2.) Iterate by index over an array so you can reuse the index to start the inner loop at the index of the first

Comment: any explanation for the downvote? In short it's the same explanation as the accepted answer (which was given while I was writing), so what's the problem?